# Google Sheets importXML Returns Empty Value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im trying to scrape this website (https://kamadan.gwtoolbox.com/) with google sheets for material costs for a game that I play.  There are two tables; "Common Materials" and "Rare Materials" in a drop down in the top right corner.  I am trying to pull the values for both as the prices update.  I copied the full Xpath and used the function below in an empty cell on a sheet.

```
=importxml("https://kamadan.gwtoolbox.com/","/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/table/tbody")
```

This returns a #N/A error saying it is returning an empty value.

I also tried it with the regular xpath...

```
=importxml("https://kamadan.gwtoolbox.com/","//*[@id='trader-overlay-items']")
```

Which just returns a blank cell.  I have also tried both methods using the inspect function through chrome on the ancestors and children they return either of the two errors above.

Sorry if this is a really easy one.  I am not familiar at all with Xpaths or html.  I mostly dabble in VBA in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*`IMPORTXML` can not retrieve data which is populated by a script, and so using this formula to retrieve data from this table is not possible to do.*

#### More Information:

As you've already mentioned, you can attempt to get the data directly from the table using:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://kamadan.gwtoolbox.com/","//table[@id='trader-overlay-items']")
```

Which just gets a blank cell.

I went a step further and tried to reverse-engineer this by calling `IMPORTXML` on the `HTML` elements on the page in steps:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://kamadan.gwtoolbox.com/","html")
=IMPORTXML("https://kamadan.gwtoolbox.com/","html/body")
=IMPORTXML("https://kamadan.gwtoolbox.com/","html/body/div[1]")
=IMPORTXML("https://kamadan.gwtoolbox.com/","html/body/div[1]/div[0]")
...
```

`html/body/div[1]/div[0]` is the first path which gives no imported content, and we can see from importing `html/body` that the full body does not contain the imformation and only a template of it - in cell `B1` we have references to 'Common materials' and 'Rare materials':

[image]

And in `D1` we start to see JavaScript and JSON objects which are not called by `IMPORTXML` and so the results of which can not be retrieved:

[image]

As you can see if you disable JavaScript on the site, almost nothing is actually rendered and so can't be obtained using `IMPORTXML`:

[image]

#### References:

- [`IMPORTXML` - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en)