# How to find the correct Xpath to get importxml function work

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use ImportXML function in Google sheets in order to bring some prices into my Google sheet, how to find the correct Xpath for this?

This is the URL:
https://www.superama.com.mx/catalogo/d-frutas-verduras/f-frutas/l-naranja-limon-y-citricos/mandarina-por-kilo/0000000003029

and I'm trying to bring the id="lblPrice" which in this case is $24.90

I was trying this formula but I'm getting NA

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.superama.com.mx/catalogo/d-frutas-verduras/f-frutas/l-naranja-limon-y-citricos/mandarina-por-kilo/0000000003029","//*[@id="lblPrice"]")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yahoo finance historical close price to google sheets returns n/a for close later than 100 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61636468/yahoo-finance-historical-close-price-to-google-sheets-returns-n-a-for-close-late)

Answer (score 0):

`IMOPORTXML`/Google Sheets does not support scraping of JavaScript elements.

[image]

Comment: got, it ... I have another site where I can also grab that, I suppose I have to post another thread for that ?
https://super.walmart.com.mx/verduras/aguacate-hass-extra-por-kilo/00000000003354