# Importing specific XPATH in google sheets from dynamic site

Tags: html, google-sheets, xpath

I'm trying to import an xpath off of a website. It's "nested" inside of a tab on the site, when changing to the correct tab inside the site the URI doesn't change in the browser and I believe this is why the information isn't pulling down correctly.

The site is https://play.staratlas.com/market/46m5C7Vy9agesyoE6otKKgeosfzyi1zGcsp4hUvuTH17
From the selection on the right I click buy, then the correct xpath is `/html/body/div/div/div[2]/main/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/span[6]/p[2]` or the last row and the dollar value on the "Ask Size" table.

The import method I'm trying is `=IMPORTXML("https://play.staratlas.com/market/46m5C7Vy9agesyoE6otKKgeosfzyi1zGcsp4hUvuTH17","/html/body/div/div/div[2]/main/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/span[6]/p[2]")` This just results in a null value.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `the last row and the dollar value on the "Ask Size" table.`. Can I ask you about the value you want to retrieve?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/MezeG3r Here's a screenshot if what I'm trying to get

Comment: There is no possibility to retrieve information using native functions like importxml. The page is built in javascript on the client side, not the server side. There is a json in the original source code, but this actually includes other calls that require a post method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yahoo finance historical close price to google sheets returns n/a for close later than 100 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61636468/yahoo-finance-historical-close-price-to-google-sheets-returns-n-a-for-close-late)