# How to extract "last updated" date from this URL to google sheets

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have tried this, but I get three dots

`=IMPORTXML("https://covid19.sabah.digital/covid19/","//span[@class='number-last_updated']")`

Comment: I think this text is coming from a JS file therefore it is impossible to query it by using `importxml`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets importXML Returns Empty Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470783/google-sheets-importxml-returns-empty-value)

Comment: =IMPORTXML("https://covid19.sabah.digital/covid19/","//div[@class='card-header font-weight-bold']")

Comment: But this one have no problem to extract..

Comment: or maybe..cannot extract data that is not static..

Comment: I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? But I'm not sure whether that is the same direction with you. So if that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw the HTML data, it seems that the last updated date is displayed by Javascript. By this, unfortunately, the value cannot be directly retrieved with `IMPORTXML`. This has already been mentioned in the comments.

When I saw the HTML data again, I noticed that the information of date is included in `https://data.covid19.sabah.digital/global.json`. From this data, how about retrieving the last updated date? In this answer, as a workaround, in order to retrieve the last updated value, I would like to propose to retrieve the data using the following sample formula.

#### Sample formula:

```
=TEXT(MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTDATA(A1),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 contains 'date'"),"\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}"))))+1,"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

- In this formula, please put the URL of `https://data.covid19.sabah.digital/global.json` to the cell "A1".
- The flow of this formula is as follows.

  1. Retrieve the JSON data using `IMPORTDATA`.
  2. Retrieve the data values from the retrieved data using `QUERY`.
  3. Convert the text to the serial number using `DATEVALUE`.
  4. Retrieve the max value using `MAX`.

     - It seems that when this value is added by `1`, it is the updated date.
     - If you don't need this, please remove `+1` from the formula.
  5. Convert the serial number to the text using `TEXT`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [IMPORTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039)
- [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013)
- [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)

Comment: Thank you very much...thats really help me there....thank you!!

Comment: @Chris Eddy Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.