# Unable to IMPORTXML

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets

The code I'm trying to access is the following.

```html
<div class="row relative">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="head-data-preview"><span class="value value--price">215.23</span> <span class="label">Cpu Amd Ryzen 5 3600XT Box [100-100000281BOX]</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I tried is :

> //div[@class='head-data-preview']//span[@itemprop='value value--price']/@content
> //div[@class='row relative']//span[@itemprop='value value--price']/@content
> //div[@class='row relative']//div[@class='head-data-preview']//span[@itemprop='value value--price']/@content

Comment: Why `@itemprop='value value--price'`? Maybe `@class='value value--price'`?

Comment: What's the website? If the data is loaded by JS then it's not retrievable with IMPORTXML. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61475850/11551468).