# Google Sheets Import XML for Retailer Pricing

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import the pricing from Best Buy's website into a Google Sheet so I don't have to load each page to check the current price of an item.

I found a solution on reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/fksh79/errors_with_pulling_price_data_with_importxml/fkw4qoz/) and using `=index(IMPORTXML(A2,"//span[@class='sr-only']"),1,3)`  to use the URL reference and look up the info works fine for most items, an example of which is [here](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/lenovo-ideapad-3-15-touch-screen-laptop-intel-core-i3-1005g1-8gb-memory-256gb-ssd-almond/6415810.p?skuId=6415810).

The issue is that this code fails on some items ([like this cell phone](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/google-pixel-5-5g-128gb-unlocked-just-black/6431992.p?skuId=6431992)) even though the same "sr-only" exists. The only way I've seen to get this to work is using the full xpath like below

`=index(IMPORTXML(A2,"/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]"),1,3)`

That returns the activate today price, I am not sure how to get this to return the full retail/activate later since the URLs are the same and the query can't change that option on the page.

I also tried using `=index(IMPORTXML(A2,"//span[@class='activated-pricing__option-price']"),1,3)` to get the full retail/activate later price of $699.99 but that fails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets importXML Returns Empty Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470783/google-sheets-importxml-returns-empty-value)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using the formula `=index(IMPORTXML(https://www.bestbuy.com/site/apple-10-2-inch-ipad-latest-model-with-wi-fi-32gb-silver/5199800.p?skuId=5199800,"//span[@class='sr-only']"),1,3)` seems to work but as you said it probably gets rate limited by Best Buy