# Attempting to import prices from Menards website to Google Sheets using IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm having trouble finding the correct xmlpath to use on the Menards site to be able to have a price list in sheets for creating estimates more easily.  I'm very inexperienced with programming but have messed around a little bit.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Sample Product:

https://www.menards.com/main/p-1444445103491.htm

Comment: There is no correct xmlpath, load your webpage with javascript disabled: "Unfortunately, ImportXML doesn’t load JavaScript, so you won’t be able to use this function if the content of the document is generated by JavaScript (jQuery, etc.)" https://rozhon.com/sheets-for-marketers/web-scraping-using-importxml-in-google-spreadsheets/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets importXML Returns Empty Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470783/google-sheets-importxml-returns-empty-value)