# Pulling Morningstar portfolio data into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I normally use **IMPORTXML** or **IMPORTHTML** succesfully on **Google Sheets** but in this case none of this works.

For example I want to see the porfolio data of the ETF *iShares Core S&P 500* [here](https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/arcx/ivv/portfolio).

**IMPORTHTML**

So let's say I want to get the data from **table #1 "Asset Class"**
(same thing will apply for other tables) and I don't want to import any graph obviously,
only texts and numbers:

```
=importhtml("https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/arcx/ivv/portfolio","table",1)
```

*The result is N/A :(*

**IMPORTXML**

I also tried importxml on the table:

```
//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "sal-asset-allocation__assetTable", " " ))]
```

but it also doesn't work.

Then I tried to find out in the network of this page and I found that it calls this [here](https://api-global.morningstar.com/sal-service/v1/etf/portfolio/regionalSectorIncludeCountries/FEUSA0000E/data?languageId=en&locale=en&clientId=MDC&benchmarkId=category&component=sal-components-mip-country-exposure&version=3.31.0).

but have no idea on how to work it around and would like to keep it simple. I'm sure someone of you can make the importhtml working.

Any suggestion? Thanks everyone, you guys saved me so many times!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets importXML Returns Empty Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470783/google-sheets-importxml-returns-empty-value)

Answer (score 0):

This website generates part of it's contents using Javascript. This part cannot be imported. Switch off javascript in your browser and see that majority of content dissapears:

[image]