# Looking to import HTML information into a Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

After multiple test and research I don't have success in importing the data of this [table](https://ecosystem.lafrenchtech.com/lists/18872/list?showGrid=false) (div) into a Google slide.

None of the formula I tested actually work included this simple test to extract the first column/line "Name":

`=importxml("https://ecosystem.lafrenchtech.com/lists/18872/list?showGrid=false", "//span[@class='table-column-text']")`

:(

Anyone could help me ?

Thx by advance.

Comment: Is it a Google Sheet or a Google Slide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

I've tested your function on a test sheet and it returns an empty content.

According to an answer at [Google Sheets importXML Returns Empty Value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61475850) , *`IMPORTXML can not retrieve data which is being populated by a script`* and it is a limitation. Unfortunately, I have checked that when Javascript is disabled for the [ecosystem.lafrenchtech.com](https://ecosystem.lafrenchtech.com/lists/18872/list?showGrid=false) site in Chrome browser, the table never loads. Thus, this confirms that the table is being populated by a script and this is the reason why it returns an empty content.

A possible alternative solution is to check if the `ecosystem.lafrenchtech.com` offers an API, where you can directly get the data that they show from their table using an API key (if it is available). However, this will require you to use Apps Script to parse the data from their API and then post it on your spreadsheet, which would be quite a tedious for a quite simple process.

***Note:***

On your post, `google-slides` was the set tag.