# Unable to get specific value in web page using '=IMPORTXML' in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get a value embedded in a website page using '=IMPORTXML' in Google Sheets:

[Example value I'm trying to capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO0Vc.png)

Here's what I tried so far: I copied the full xpath in Google Chrome and entered the following in Google Sheets:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://magiceden.io/marketplace/portals","//html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/text")
```

But it returns 'N/A' in my google sheets cell, saying it's empty.

I tried to do the same on the Solanafloor website and that did work. Example:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://solanafloor.com/nft/portals","//html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/main/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/strong/span/text()")
```

In both cases I used 'copy full xpath' in Google Chrome and used that exact value for the formula.
Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this [Answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115665)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets importXML Returns Empty Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470783/google-sheets-importxml-returns-empty-value)

Comment: no wayn this site uses javascript that is not compatible with native functions https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun

Comment: It is, sadly this means it won't work. But it was indeed due to the javascript on the page. Thanks!